# Using Camel Processor as custom component

Tags: components, apache-camel

I want to make a custom camel processor to behave as a custom component.I read it as it as possible from http://camel.apache.org/processor.html - section--> Turning your processor into a full component.
Here the Custom Processor created will have to do the job when i call
**someComponent://action1?param1=value1&param2=value2**
in the route.

For this i created a sample component using maven catalog.This created Endpoint,Consumer, Producer and Component classes.

The link says that the component should return ProcessorEndpoint which i have done.
So, Endpoint looks as below

```
public class SampleEndpoint extends ProcessorEndpoint{
 // Automatically Generated code begins
  public Producer createProducer() throws Exception{
            return new SampleProducer(this, processor);
  }

  public Consumer createConsumer() throws Exception{
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This operation is not permitted....");
 }
 // Automatically generated code ends here

 //added below to make custom processor work for custom component
  public Processor createProcessor(Processor processor){
     return new SampleProcessor();
  }
}
```

But, here the code in the processor is not getting executed instead the code in the SampleProducer gets executed.
Here i want the processor to be excuted.How do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

When extending ProcessorEndpoint, the Producer from **createProducer()** will handle the exchange, i.e. **Producer.process(Exchange exchange)**.

This is why you are seeing **SampleProducer** being used. But if you wanted to delegate to a processor, you could probably just change your code to be:

```
return new SampleProducer(this, new SampleProcessor());
```

My best advice would be to attach a debugger and put breakpoints in your SampleEndpoint, SampleProducer and SampleProcessor methods to see what gets called and when.